# database with ruby on rails for different language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I want to create a site with ruby on rails which would  have 10 000 records . I want this site to be in different languages. What is the best way to create a database for this site?
One schema for every language or a big schema with different table for every language?

Comment: https://github.com/globalize/globalize

Answer (score 1):

You're best bet is using the globalize gem, it allows you to translate attributes of your models very easily. https://github.com/globalize/globalize

An example from their readme.

```
I18n.locale = :en
post.title # => Globalize rocks!

I18n.locale = :he
post.title # => גלובאלייז2 שולט!
```